# Are child controls painted after the parent Window?

Tags: c, winapi

Say I have the following Window with a Button:

[image]

If I minimize and restore the Window, then two `WM_PAINT` messages will be sent, one for the Window and one for the Button.

The `WM_PAINT` message for the Window will request that the entire Window to be repainted, and the `WM_PAINT` message for the Button will request that the Button to be repainted.

What if the Button is repainted first, and then the Window is repainted, wouldn't this means that the painting for the Window will cover the Button and make it invisible? So does that means that the Window is painted before the Button?

Comment: Windows uses the *painter's algorithm*.  Bottom first.  So your imagined failure mode just doesn't occur.  Even if the app has a bug and does it the wrong way around then the WS_CLIPCHILDREN style flag still prevents trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are child controls painted after the parent Window?

Yes.

Painting for children with the same parent (siblings) is rather complex. That topics is covered here: [MSDN: Child Window Update Region](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183426.aspx).

Comment: I came across this while I was looking for documentation backup for an answer. You've got it the wrong way around (last sentence), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183426(v=vs.85).aspx .